# Error before make the python executable with auto-py-yo-exe NameError: name '__version__' is not definied [3644] Failed to execute the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, exe, autopy

I tried to create an exe with auto py to exe but when I tried to execute it It throws an error. I tried to execute it as admin but it doesn't make any difference.

[image: Error Image Here]

Comment: Please post some code so we can take a look at what might be going wrong. Feel free to @ me when you do so that I can take a look and try to help you with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is being caused in the `pyppeteer` package. Go to the `__init__` file of the package and replace the **version** with the version you are currently using.

In order to find the location of `pyppeteer\__init__.py`, you can type `pip show pyppeteer` and the directory will be listed under `Location`.

To find out the version you are currently using, use `pip show pyppeteer`. In my case, it would return "0.2.5", so I would set `__version__ =  "0.2.5"`. Try to make the application an executable again and it should work just fine.